# Getting Sphider to output JSON

Tags: json, sphider

I've recently added the [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/) crawler to my site in order to add search functionality. But the default search.php that comes with the distribution of Sphider that I downloaded is too plain and doesn't integrate well with the rest of my site. I have a little navigation bar at the top of the site which has a search box in it, and I'd like to be able to access Sphider's search results through that search field using Ajax. To do this, I figure I need to get Sphider to return its results in JSON format.

The way I did that is I used a "theme" that outputs JSON (Sphider supposts "theming" its output). I found that theme on [this thread](http://www.sphider.eu/forum/read.php?3,6210) on Sphider's site. It *seems* to work, but more strict JSON parsers will not parse it. Here's some example JSON output:

```
{"result_report":"Displaying results 1 - 1 of 1 match (0 seconds) ", "results":[ { "idented":"false", "num":"1", "weight":"[100.00%]", "link":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles/Triple_Contraints", "title":"Triple Contraints", "description":" on 01/06/12 Project triple constraints are time, cost, and quality. These are the three constraints that control the performance of the project. Think about this triple-constraint as a three-leg tripod. If one of the legs is elongated or", "link2":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles/Triple_Contraints", "size":"3.3kb" }, { "num":"-1" } ], "other_pages":[ { "title":"1", "link":"search.php?query=constraints&start=1&search=1&results=10&type=and&domain=", "active":"true" }, ] }
```

The issue is that there is a trailing comma near the end. According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), "trailing commas are not allowed" when using PHP's `json_decode()` function. This JSON also failed to parse using [this](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) online formatter. But when I took the comma out, it worked and I got this better-formatted JSON:

```
{
   "result_report":"Displaying results 1 - 1 of 1 match (0 seconds) ",
   "results":[
      {
         "idented":"false",
         "num":"1",
         "weight":"[100.00%]",
         "link":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles/Triple_Contraints",
         "title":"Triple Contraints",
         "description":" on 01/06/12 Project triple constraints are time, cost, and quality. These are the three constraints that control the performance of the project. Think about this triple-constraint as a three-leg tripod. If one of the legs is elongated or",
         "link2":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles/Triple_Contraints",
         "size":"3.3kb"
      },
      {
         "num":"-1"
      }
   ],
   "other_pages":[
      {
         "title":"1",
         "link":"search.php?query=constraints&start=1&search=1&results=10&type=and&domain=",
         "active":"true"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, how would I do this programmatically? And (perhaps more importantly), is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this? And you should know that PHP is the only language I can run on my shared hosting account, so a Java solution for example would not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the code that generate the piece of JSON above?

Comment: I have. The original code also surrounded this JSON with parens. I got rid of that, but the trailing comma is somewhat less trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `search_result.html`, you can surround the `,` at the end of the foreach loop with condition to only print if the index is strictly less than the number of pages - 1.