# Invalid characters in JSON output

Tags: database, json

I'm getting some JSON from my server that represents search results. I'm getting it from Sphider, which is a PHP search engine. I already asked about getting the JSON in the first place [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888704/getting-sphider-to-output-json), if you're interested.

So this JSON looks okay to me. When I put it into [this validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), it's saying "Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 66]" I'm not sure what this means, but I figured I should take a look at the line its complaining about more closely to see if there are any strange characters. All I found were 0x20s (spaces) where the spaces *should* be.

Now, here's I think the biggest hint: when I copy the "invalid" JSON from the validator's output into the input and run it again, it works, saying that the JSON is valid. I'm not sure what to make of that.

So what does the validator mean? Also, this text is pulled from a database, what could be causing it to output "invalid characters"?

Here's the JSON:

```
{   "result_report":"Displaying results 1 - 2 of 2 matches (0.03 seconds) ",  "results":[    {   "idented":"false",   "num":"1",  "weight":"[100.00%]",  "link":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles/PHP_Markdown",  "title":"PHP <b>Markdown</b>",   "description":"  Full documentation of <b>Markdown</b>'s syntax is available on John's <b>Markdown</b> page: http://daringfireball.net/projects/<b>Markdown</b>/   Installation and Requirement  PHP <b>Markdown</b> requires PHP version 4.0.5 or later.  WordPress  PHP <b>Markdown</b>",  "link2":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles/PHP_Markdown",  "size":"31.0kb" },  {   "idented":"false",   "num":"2",  "weight":"[3.46%]",  "link":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles",  "title":"Recent Articles",   "description":" systems         PHP <b>Markdown</b>     by Some Guy     Some information regarding using the PHP <b>Markdown</b> library, it's deployment, and some things to watch out for.            MD Example      by Hassan El-Mehalawi       A simple example",  "link2":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles",  "size":"3.3kb" },  {  "num":"-1" }  ],  "other_pages":[   {  "title":"1",  "link":"search.php?query=markdown&start=1&search=1&results=10&type=and&domain=",      "active":"true"     }     ]  }
```

And here it is formatted:

```
{
   "result_report":"Displaying results 1 - 2 of 2 matches (0.03 seconds) ",
   "results":[
      {
         "idented":"false",
         "num":"1",
         "weight":"[100.00%]",
         "link":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles/PHP_Markdown",
         "title":"PHP <b>Markdown</b>",
         "description":"  Full documentation of <b>Markdown</b>'s syntax is available on John's <b>Markdown</b> page: http://daringfireball.net/projects/<b>Markdown</b>/   Installation and Requirement  PHP <b>Markdown</b> requires PHP version 4.0.5 or later.  WordPress  PHP <b>Markdown</b>",
         "link2":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles/PHP_Markdown",
         "size":"31.0kb"
      },
      {
         "idented":"false",
         "num":"2",
         "weight":"[3.46%]",
         "link":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles",
         "title":"Recent Articles",
         "description":" systems       PHP <b>Markdown</b>    by Some Guy   Some information regarding using the PHP <b>Markdown</b> library, it's deployment, and some things to watch out for.         MD Example    by Hassan El-Mehalawi   A simple example",
         "link2":"http://www.avtainsys.com/articles",
         "size":"3.3kb"
      },
      {
         "num":"-1"
      }
   ],
   "other_pages":[
      {
         "title":"1",
         "link":"search.php?query=markdown&start=1&search=1&results=10&type=and&domain=",
         "active":"true"
      }
   ]
}
```

To be clear the formatted JSON was formatted with the formatter/validator I linked to above. This is the output I get after putting in the original "invalid" output.

Since, it's been observed that the unformatted JSON above is actually valid, here is the URL that would output the above JSON:

http://avtainsys.com/sphider/search.php?query=markdown&search=1

Comment: This is a wild guess, so im not going to put it as a answer, but might it be the `<b>` tags? it might not like the `<`, but when you copy it from the web output it would be converted to `%3C;` which the JSON might like better

redacted : tested it on the validator and JSON doesnt mind < chars, didnt think it should either so that makes sense.

Comment: But I can still see the "<b>" tags in the formatted JSON. Did I miss one?

Comment: When I copy and paste your JSON from this site to the validator I get no error. This would be hard to figure out with being able to recreate the error.

Comment: @gbtimmon Uh oh you're right. I just copied the JSON from this page, and it worked, but the same JSON straight from the server gives an error. This is somewhat problematic.

Comment: When I put that into the validator, is says it's valid. Chrome can parse it too.

Comment: When you say "straight from the server" how are you actually parsing it? Are you rendering this as a string like `var json = '{ the JSON }')`? Maybe you need to escape the apostrophes.

Comment: @jamietre No I mean when I validated it with the validator, I typed in the URL that would output that JSON, copy-pasted it into the validator and got the error. I just tried it again to be sure.

Comment: @jamietre I updated my question to include the actual URL that outputs that JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with tabs; it parses (from the actual source) after cleaning up whitespace in the string identified by the validator. Technically tabs should be escaped as `\t` in JSON strings (though it is possible some parsers may not care).

Comment: That was indeed the problem. From another PHP I replaced "\t" with " " (a space), and that worked.